# Do pieces of wire or metal in general affect the inside of a Faraday cage

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, telecommunications

Building a Faraday cage and wanted to know do the dozens of metal staples and several small pieces of wire have any effect in terms of acting as an antenna?

Comment: No way to answer without more information.  What are the frequencies of interest? How big are any gaps? Show a drawing of your proposed enclosure with some details.

Answer (score 0):

as the pieces of metal tarnish/rust/oxidize/get_covered_with_pollution, your shielding effectiveness will drop. And vibration will disrupt the initial metal-to-metal joints.